# CMake Error When Installing libfreenect w/ Python Wrapper

Tags: python, cmake, kinect, cython

I am trying to install libfreenect with the Python wrapper on my Windows 8 (64-bit) laptop.  I am using Python 3.4.3 in Anaconda 2.3.0.  I seem to have all of the dependencies taken care of, but when I try and configure the build in the cmake gui, I get the following error:

```
Operating system is Windows
Got System Processor AMD64
libfreenect will be installed to C:/Program Files/libfreenect
Headers will be installed to C:/Program Files/libfreenect/include/libfreenect
Libraries will be installed to C:/Program Files/libfreenect/lib
Found libusb-1.0:
 - Includes: C:/libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0/include
 - Libraries: C:/libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0/lib/msvc_i64/libusb.lib
   Entering             C:/libfreenect/src
   Returning to         C:/libfreenect
   Entering             C:/libfreenect/examples
   Returning to         C:/libfreenect
   Entering             C:/libfreenect/wrappers/c_sync
   Returning to         C:/libfreenect
   Entering             C:/libfreenect/wrappers/python
    CMake Error at wrappers/python/CMakeLists.txt:35 (install):
      install TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for module target
      "cython_freenect".


   Returning to         C:/libfreenect
   Entering             C:/libfreenect/OpenNI2-FreenectDriver
   Returning to         C:/libfreenect
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/libfreenect/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I am following the installation instructions from here:
http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Windows

I am following the specific Python instruction from here:
http://openkinect.org/wiki/Python_Wrapper_Windows

Anybody have any experience with this cmake error?  The goal is to be able to interface with my Microsoft Kinect.  I can provide more information as needed.

EDIT: Added verbose version of cmake configuration output.

Comment: According to your output, you have empty `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable (`libfreenect will be installed to`). Probably, you suddenly clear its value. Set its value (in cmake-gui) to `c:/Program Files` and rerun cmake (`Configure` button).

Comment: I just did that with no success.  Same error except that it says that it will install to that directory.  I noticed that the cmakefile prints in the Python version 2 format vs. 3 which I am currently using.  I have even tried modifying this file to comply with the Python 3 format, but I still get the same error. https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/blob/master/wrappers/python/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Hmm, according to error message, it seems that variable `PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES` has empty value. It is set to the output of the python one-line script at `wrappers/python/CMakeLists.txt:12`. Can you try to execute that command alone? (`PYTHON_EXECUTABLE` is `python2`, `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is one you enter).

Comment: That is the issue that I thought could be wrong since I use Python 3.  I did manually set PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES in cmake.  I also tried altering the cmakefile to read `${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib(prefix='${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}'))"`.  That command works in my Python terminal, but it doesn't fix the cmake configuration.  One odd thing is that this command outputs `C:/Program Files\Lib\site-packages` with mix-matched slashes separating directories...

Comment: As far as I know, mixing slaches is OK for paths in cmake. At least, variable should be set, and error message should be different from one you observe.  Can you check, whether `PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES` is empty or not(using `message()` cmake command just before variable is used)?

Comment: You are right, it appears to be empty.  Unless I am using the command wrong `message("TEST: ${PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES}")`. The "TEST" part was to make sure the command was actually executing.  This is odd because I manually set it in cmake, but perhaps I am overwriting it with an empty string?

Comment: Noticed another issue playing around with the message command...it says it is Python 2; however, I have Python 3 set in cmake.  Any reason why it is ignoring this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a workaround.  For some funny reason, libfreenect or cmake thinks I have Python2 which messed up the rest of the Makefile listed in the comments section.  After the include files (in case they are the culprit), I manually set the variable with the `set(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE "C:/Users/user/Anaconda3/python.exe")` and it generated correctly.  I am now going to compile it which is a completely separate issue  Thank-you Tsavarev!